# Calling Python scripts in a nested structure stored in higher levels within the structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to call a script a couple of levels up in a nested folder structure. Each level has a **init**.py file so that Python recognises the folders as packages. My structure is as so:

```
Master
__init__.py
script_a.py
----Sub_Folder
----__init__.py
----script_b.py
--------Sub_Sub_Folder
--------__init__.py
--------script_c.py
```

I am trying to import script_a to script_c using the below statement:

```
from Master import script_a
```

...however I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Master'
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imports should be relative to the folder you run your script from. If you are running your script from the `Master` folder and want to import `script_a.py` in `script_c.py`, you should simply do:

```
import script_a
```

instead.

Comment: Script_c is being run from Sub_Sub_Folder

Comment: You have to run `script_c` from `Master`; otherwise `script_a` would not be considered to be part of the same project as `script_c` and you would not be able to import `script_a` without adding the absolute path of `Master` to `sys.path`. To run `script_c` from `Master`, you would `cd` into `Master`, and then do `python Sub_Folder/Sub_Sub_Folder/script_c`.

Answer (score 0):

for example You are on script_c and and you want to import script_b
Then you can call

```
from Sub_Folder import script_b
```

or

```
from .. import script_b
```

for calling script_a from script_c use three dots.One dot represents current directory.Two dots represent previous directory and three dots represent previous  of previous directory

```
from ... import script_a
```

or

```
import script_a
```

if you want to import script from current directory you should use

```
from . import __init__
```